# Shortcut toolbar windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1

How can I create a shortcut toolbar on my desktop, in windows 8.1 ?

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/create-a-shortcut-toolbar-on-the-desktop

Comment: So this does not work on the W8.1 desktop? I assume you tried it, what happened when you did?

Comment: I know nothing of [this software that claims to do what you want](http://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/coolbarz.html)

Comment: Does not support Windows 8.1 and it's been abandoned, and it's also hosted on a horrible website :$

Comment: Just pin shortcuts to the menu bar.

Comment: @Mohab: When I tried to move the empty folder near the screen edge nothing happened.  --Ramgound I already have shortcuts pinned to the menu bar and I do not like it. That's why I've asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, that feature is no longer available and I'm not aware of anything to replace it.

However, 1 thing is still possible which is to use additional toolbars. You can create additional toolbars which are simply folders with links in them.

You can then widen your taskbar to show multiple toolbars or, as I do, leave on tucked in as close as possible to the indicator icon area with a heading - I use "Menu", you get a double chevron that indicates an area to click on to expand the "menu".